# Can't type autoComplete Data type when creating table columns

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

I would like to be able to type into the Data Type and have it auto complete or at the very least just let me type the type I want to use.

However you are unable to write in this box at all. Only click the box and have to scroll very slowly through all of the types.

[image]